# python - parse encoded json file - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, json, unicode, encode

One json file that I need to parse seems to be encoded and the code fails with the error:
***ValueError***: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 3 (char 4)

My question are, how to I convert/load the json? 
Single-quotes or double-quotes in the json makes a difference? 
Is a good solution to find/replace single to double quotes and the Unicode character `u` in order to parse the json?

**json:**

```
  {
      'data': [
          {'ad_id': u'372900', 'adset_id': u'72900', 'campaign_id': u'363200', 'created_time': u'2016-03-08'},
          {'ad_id': u'372900', 'adset_id': u'72900', 'campaign_id': u'363200', 'created_time': u'2016-03-08'}
    ]
  }
```

code snipet:

```
import json
import pprint
with open('leads.json') as data_file:
       data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

Comment: That isn't a json file, it's a python module. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I got it as an example of data parsed from facebook, but I've no idea how it was parsed. For me it is also a weird format and a mess to handle.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that json expects double quotes to surround strings.  You have single quotes (and python unicode markers e.g. `u'372900'`).  So your file isn't valid json.  You still might be able to parse it though.  Try `ast.literal_eval` on the file contents and see if that works.

```
import ast
with open('leads.json') as data_file:
   data = ast.literal_eval(data_file.read())
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think literal_eval evaluates a multiline literal expression like that fine

Comment: Thanks, since my input data is in this format and seems it was encoded as Windows-1252, would it be possible to encode/convert it into utf-8 format?